# How to remove borders from the legend without removing borders from the bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
require(ggplot2)



data2<-structure(list(IR = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("0.13-0.16", "0.17-0.23", "0.24-0.27", "0.28-1"
), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Real queens", "Simulated individuals"
), class = "factor"), value = c(15L, 11L, 29L, 42L, 0L, 5L, 21L, 
22L), Legend = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Real queens", 
"Simulated individuals"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("IR", 
"variable", "value", "Legend"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
p <- ggplot(data2, aes(x =factor(IR), y = value, fill = Legend, width=.15))


data3<-structure(list(IR = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("0.13-0.16", "0.17-0.23", "0.24-0.27", "0.28-1"
), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Real queens", "Simulated individuals"
), class = "factor"), value = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
4L), Legend = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Real queens", 
"Simulated individuals"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("IR", 
"variable", "value", "Legend"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
q<- ggplot(data3, aes(x =factor(IR), y = value, fill = Legend, width=.15))


##the plot##
q + geom_bar(position='dodge', colour='black') + ylab('Frequency') + 
        xlab('IR')+scale_fill_grey() +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="Black"))+ 
        opts(title='', panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),panel.grid.minor = 
        theme_blank(),panel.border = theme_blank(),panel.background = 
        theme_blank(), axis.ticks.x = theme_blank())
```

I want to keep the black border effect

```
geom_bar(colour='black)
```

without having that weird diagonal dash across the blocks depicted in the legend. Is there any way to decouple those or remove that diagonal dash?

Comment: See example in [r cookbook webpage](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) (last example)

Comment: It's the same data with a completely different question. I was under the impression that was protocol. Also, I didn't know there was a cost to asking 4 questions in an hour. I was on a plane all day yesterday and came up with a list of questions I couldn't solve.

Comment: Didzis Elferts, that worked beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Didzis Elferts mentioned, there's an example of this [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) (last example).

The trick is to superimpose two plots: the first plot takes care of the legend in the desired way, and the second plot lacks a legend but adds borders to the actual plot itself.